# Which hadith is this?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

> Muslim (315) narrated that Thawbaan, the freed slave of the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: 
>   I was standing beside the Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) when one of the Jewish rabbis came and said: Peace be upon you, O Muhammad. I gave him a shove that almost made him fall over and he said: Why did you push me? I said: Why don’t you say, O Messenger of Allah? The Jew said: We only call him by the name that his family gave him. The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “My name is Muhammad, that my family gave to me.” The Jew said: I have come to ask you something. The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Will it benefit you anything if I tell you?” He said: I will listen. The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) scratched the ground with a stick that he had with him and said: “Ask.” The Jew said: Where will the people be on the Day when the earth is changed to another earth and the heavens (likewise)? The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “They will be in darkness near the bridge.” He said: Who will be the first people to cross (the bridge)? He said: “The poor muhaajireen.” The Jew said: What will be presented to them when they enter Paradise? He said: “The choicest pieces of whale’s liver.” He said: What food will be given to them after that? He said: The bull of Paradise, which used to graze along its edges, will be slaughtered for them.” He said: What will their drink be? He said: “From a spring there that is called Salsabeel.” He said: You have spoken the truth. I came to ask you about something that no one on earth knows except a Prophet or one or two men. He said: “Will it benefit you anything if I tell you?” He said: I will listen. I have come to ask you about the child. He said: “The water of the man is white and the water of the woman is yellow. If they meet and the maniy of the man prevails over the maniy of the woman, it will be a male, by Allah's leave. If the maniy of the woman prevails over the maniy of the man, it will be a female, by Allah’s leave.” The Jew said: You have spoken the truth; you are indeed a Prophet. Then he left and went away. The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “This man asked me what he asked me, and I had no knowledge of any of that until Allah granted it to me.”

Can anyone tell me the the vol no., book no., and hadith no. of the above hadith?

The closest hadith to this that I found is [Sahih Bukari, Vol. 6, Book 60, Hadith 7](https://quranx.com/Hadith/Bukhari/USC-MSA/Volume-6/Book-60/Hadith-7/)

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: The volume and number of the hadith depend strongly from the edition and editor (count).

Answer (score 2):

It says "Muslim (315)" so it is from Saheeh Muslim Hadith number 315, on your linked website it is here: https://quranx.com/Hadith/Muslim/Reference/Hadith-315a Volume, Hadith Number etc. is all subjective and change according to publication and edition.

Searching for the exact words you quote brings up this [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/175100/views-of-the-scholars-and-doctors-on-the-role-of-the-mans-water-and-the-womans-water-in-determining-the-gender-of-the-foetus) question. Going to the [arabic](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/175100/%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%89%D9%88%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%84-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%86) version of the question gives the arabic text, which you use to find it irrespective of the number, volume, english translation etc.